# Jquery Asual Address - Back Button PopState

Tags: jquery, history, pushstate

I am trying to use the [Asual Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) plug in so that my back button works on ajax calls.  I am so confused on how this work and every tutorial i find says to impliment it different.  I haven't been able to get any of them to work.

I have a simple ajax page.  It simply calls in an image:

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    


$("a").live("click", function(event) {      
    url = $(this).attr("href");
     $.address.value($(this).attr('href')); 
    event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "/"+url+".php",
            data: "",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(html){
                jQuery('#Right_Content').hide().html(html).fadeIn(1000);
            },
         })

});
</script>
```

My Html Looks like this:

```
<body>
<a href="push1" onclick="return false;" >Image 1</a>
<a href="push2" onclick="return false;">Image 2</a>  

<div id="Right_Content"></div>

</body>
```

Using the code above, when i click a link it makes the ajax call, loads the pics and changes the url.  This is working fine.  My problem is the back button.  When i click the back button the url changes to the previous url but the content on the page stays the same.  I think it has something to do with "popstate" and adding this to my js.  I just don't know how to it.

Can someone please explain to me how popstate works and how i add it to my above code so that my back button works.  Thank you.

**FULL PAGE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script src="/JS_Functions/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/JS_Functions/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="JS_Functions/jquery.address-1.4/jquery.address-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.address.init(function(event) {
  // All elements with the "history" class will be "addressed". When they get clicked
  // the href will get used as the new #part of the URL
$('a').address();
$('a').live("click", function(){
    var href = $(this).attr( "href" );  
    $.ajax({
                        type: "get",
                        url: "/"+href+".php",
                        data: "",
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function(html){
                        jQuery('#Right_Content').hide().html(html).fadeIn(1000);
                        },               
    })

})
}).change(function(event) {
  //Every time the url part changes this will be called. 

  // As an example here I determine the # part of the URL and default to 'home'
  var hash = event.path.substring(1);
  hash = hash? hash.toLowerCase(): 'push1';

  //.. do the stuff here that you need to do when hash has a certain value

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="push1" >Image 1</a>
<a href="push2" >Image 2</a>  

<div id="Right_Content"></div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

My task was to allow user to go back in forth for some pages, and prevent go back without a message that he will lose the data, from other pages. I ended implemented this way:

```
$(".-step-1-").click(function () {
   $.address.value("");
});

$(".-step-2-").click(function () {
    $.address.value("finances");
});

$(".-step-3-").click(function () {
    $.address.value("cofirmation");
});

global.previousPage = null;
$.address.init(function () {
}).change(function () {
}).externalChange(function (event) {
    if (global.previousPage == null) {
        $.address.value("");
    } else {
        showPageExternal(event.pathNames);
    }
}).internalChange(function (event) {
    global.previousPage = event.pathNames;
    showPage(event.pathNames);
});

var showPageExternal = function (pathName) {
    if (global.previousPage == null ||
        ("").localeCompare(global.previousPage) === 0 ||
        ("finances").localeCompare(global.previousPage) === 0) {
        showPage(pathName);
    }
    else {
        //This mean is coming from "confirmation" page
        global.blockUI($("#browserBackMessage"));
    }
};

var showPage = function (pathName) {
    if (("").localeCompare(pathName) === 0) {
        $(".step").hide();
        $(".-step-1").show();
    }
    if (("finances").localeCompare(pathName) === 0) {
        $(".step").hide();
        $("#finances").show();
    }
    if (("confirmation").localeCompare(pathName) === 0) {
        $(".step").hide();
        $("#confirm").show();
    }
};

global = function globalVariable() {
    return (function () { return this; })();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used on http://www.isaac.nl/en/

I have this HTML there:

```
<div id="main-menu">    
  <a class="history" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a class="history" href="#who">who</a>
  <a class="history" href="#what"></a>
  <a class="history" href="#where"></a>  
</div>
```

In a js file I do this:

```
$.address.init(function(event) {
  // All elements with the "history" class will be "addressed". When they get clicked
  // the href will get used as the new #part of the URL
  $('.history').address();

}).change(function(event) {
  //Every time the url part changes this will be called. 

  // As an example here I determine the # part of the URL and default to 'home'
  var hash = event.path.substring(1);
  hash = hash? hash.toLowerCase(): 'home';

  //.. do the stuff here that you need to do when hash has a certain value
});
```

Comment: Thanks. :) What's your latest minimal code + html? do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: I have updated my code above with my entire page so that you can see whats going on.  It runs the ajax fine and changes the hash but when i hit the back button it doesn't step through the states it just jumps all the way back to the 1st page.  So the back buttons aren't working as they should with the plug in.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If you add a console.log in de .change handler does it show up in the logs when you click on a link? If it doesn't then you haven't correctly used the address() correctly.

Comment: I emailed ASUAL expressing my frustration with not being able to figure this out. I attached my code in the email and before the day was over i had a response email from them with a working version of my code.  I was so impressed that they responded and fixed my code that i made a donation.  Thank you for your help, your answer above was very close to the code they sent me.

Comment: Good to hear. It would be good for stackoverflow that you post the solution so that other people can see the solution as well. I have used a couple of these "history/ back button" plugins and ASUAL is by far the best I have used